# Sending POST request with Image PHP without using forms

Tags: python, php, post, request

I have this code in Python

```
 response = requests.post(
            'https://telegra.ph/upload',
            files=files
        ).json()
```

and I want to write this in PHP, the problem is I can't find any solution except the ones that talk about using forms and sending the image to the specified URL in POST format. Is there any way to do that without using forms, ie a PHP script that has a link to an image, and when the script is run, it simply sends a post request to the URL with that image and get the response. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: To clarify, you want to send the POST request from the server that is running the PHP script, and not from the web browser that is displaying the web page that is the output of the PHP script?

Comment: Yes, I want to send the POST request from the server that is running the PHP script and not from the web browser that is displaying the web page.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i found a code online that solved my problem.

```
$ch = curl_init();
$cFile = new CURLFile('mypicture.png', 'image/png', 'mypicture');
$data = array("files"=> $cFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://telegra.ph/upload/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Thank you everyone for your time.